# Parse error on map input with own data type

Tags: dictionary, haskell, concatenation, fold

SO I am trying to make a function Where I am able to concatenate strings or ints and I am having issues with it.

The custom data type I have is

```
data AnEither  = AString String | AnInt Int
                deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

I wrote this concat function for strings and it worked correctly

```
concatAll :: [[AnEither]] -> AnEither
concatAll [[]] = ""
concatAll x = foldr (++) "" (map concat x)
```

and now I am kind of confused on how to do it with the multiple data types.

I created this helper function

```
concatHelper :: AnEither -> AnEither -> AnEither
concatHelper Nothing x = x
concatHelper x Nothing = x
concatHelper x y = x ++ (show y)
```

and then this other concat function

```
concat2Either:: [[AnEither]] -> AnEither
concat2Either x = foldr concatHelper '' (map (foldr concatAll "") x)
```

So basically if I input concat2Either [[AString "", AnInt 0],[]]
it will output

"AString "0""

I am having trouble firstly with the parse error with map and then how to fully go about these functions

I am getting this error for map

error: parse error on input ‘map’
|
56 | concat2Either x = foldr concatHelper '' (map (foldr concatAll "") x)

Comment: You do not convert the `ANEither` to a string, the return type is also `AnEither`... In your `concatHelper`, you are working with `Maybe` types, but the signature indicates you are working with `AnEither`s, furterhmore `show y` will, in case it is an `AnEither` return `"AString \"foo\""` or `"AnInt 2"`, not `"foo"` or `"2"`. I would advice to first define the correct signatures, since that will also make the error messages a lot more sensical.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I should clarify that the output is supposed to be "AString "0""